# How to remove function when I change screen size (menu responsive)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // get width of screen
    var Docwidth = 0;
    $(window).resize(function () {
        Docwidth = $(document).width();

        //if width of document smaller screen

        if (Docwidth < 768) {
            //turn on accordion
            $('#accordion').accordion({
                heightStyle: false
            });
        } else {
            // turn off function when i change screen size
            $('#accordion').accordion("disable");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Could you be more specific? Which function you want to remove?

Comment: Can you make it an actual question?

Comment: Have you tried $('#accordion').accordion("destroy") ?

Comment: Make sure your if else logic is outside the document ready, since it will be executed only in document ready state but not is resize.

Comment: what i want to remove accordion function when i change screen size smaller 768px and make it active again when i change screen bigger 768px

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
// get width of screen
var Docwidth = 0;
    testWindowWidth();
});

$(window).resize(function () {
   testWindowWidth();
});

function testWindowWidth(){
     Docwidth = $(document).width();   

    //if width of document smaller screen

    if (Docwidth < 768) {
        //turn on accordion
       $('#accordion').accordion({
            heightStyle: false
        });

    } else {
        // turn off function when i change screen size

        $('#accordion').accordion("disable");

    }
}
```

You have to set the function '**$(window).resize();**' out of the "***$(document).ready();***"-Function, because in "ready" it will run only ones.

Hope I could help.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dntnokhg/3/) <- You have to change innerWindow of the red block :)